# Prevent a multi-select input box from deselecting all the options if the user clicks a single record

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to prevent a multi-select input box from deselecting all the options if the user clicks a single record without using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button?

This way they would have to click the item from the list to turn it on or off and the other values would always stay either selected or unselected unless the user explicitly clicks on them to toggle their selected status.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, not yet. A return false; on a click event, but the deselect seems to happen in the dom before jquery can pick up the click and the previous values.

Comment: _Is there a way to prevent a multi-select input box from deselecting all the options if the user clicks a single record with using the Ctrl button?_ This doesn't happen for me. Do you mean if the user _doesn't_ hold down the Ctrl key

Answer (score 1):

You can hook the option click and then if there are none left selected, re-select the item:

```
$("option").click(function (e) 
    {
        if ($(this).attr("selected") != "selected")
        {
            if($(this).parent().find("option:selected").length == 0)
                $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
        }           
    });​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/7GZkL/12/